# onbeforeunload not working - tried everything

Tags: javascript

I have tried a lot of things for onbeforeunload and came up with a solution-

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(e) {
    (e || window.event).returnValue = null;
    return null;
});
```

This seems to work when i navigate away from the current page inside the application, but its not working for which it is intended that is on browser close. i want this to work only on browser close and not on navigating by clicking on other links inside the application. Any leads will be appretiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)